# Does default == operator implentation calls ReferenceEquals internally in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I know that `==` operator implentation only do reference check by default, and it doesn't call `Object.Equals` virtual method. Since `Object` class also have a `ReferenceEquals` method that does reference check, so does `==` operator default implentation calls `Object.ReferenceEquals` method internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of `==` for a class (not a struct) that has no `==` operator overload defined, is to do a straight reference comparison with a `ceq` instruction. It **does not** call `ReferenceEquals` (which cannot be overridden as it is `static`).

[The code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs) for `ReferenceEquals` is quite simple:

```cs
public static bool ReferenceEquals (Object objA, Object objB) {
        return objA == objB;
    }
```

So it's exactly the same thing.

Comment: Beat me to it. But the link to the source for `Object` is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs).

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was quoting, have added link

Comment: @Zer0 Not if you haven't defined a comparison. Then you just get compiler error CS0019

Comment: For `Equals` on [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype.equals?view=net-5.0#remarks), including structs: The default implementation calls Object.Equals(Object) on each field.  For `==` on structs use operator overloads.

Comment: @Charlieface so default implementation of `==` for a class uses `ceq` instruction, which is the same effect as calling `ReferenceEquals`, is it correct?

Comment: Yes correct. `ReferenceEquals` also compiles to `ceq`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for your answer, anthoer question is,  what about default implementation of `==` for a struct?

Comment: There is none. It will cause a syntax error unless an `==` overload exists. For basic CIL types such as `int` and `float`, the compiler issues `ceq`, which does a value comparison obviously, as it is a valuetype

Answer (score 1):

1. `==` checks for equality
2. `ReferenceEquals` checks for identity
3. Identity assumes equality, equality does not assume identity
4. `==` and `Equals` on a reference type defaults to a reference check, howevercan be overridden by its actual type, `ReferenceEquals` cannot

Going further via the CLI ECMA specs

**Identity**

- If the values have different exact types (cat and dog), then they are not identical.
- If their exact type is a value type, then they are identical if and only if the bit sequences of the values are the same (bit by bit)
- If their exact type is a reference type, then they are identical if and only if the locations of the values are the same in memory.

**Equality**

- Equality is baked into value types and part of its exact type
- Identity should imply equality
- If either (or both) operand is a boxed value, equality should be computed by

  - first unboxing any boxed operand(s), and then
  - applying the usual rules for equality on the resulting values.

Identity is implemented via the `ReferenceEquals`. Equality is implemented via the `Equals` method.

**Some examples**

- The types `Cat` and `Dog` if not in a hierarchical relationship can never be identical.
- If `Cat` and `Dog` are separate instances, they can’t be identical.
- Casting a reference type `Cat` to `Mammal`, preserves the identity and are identical
- `(byte)4` and `(int)4` are not identical however they are equivalent
- `(byte)4` and `(byte)4` are identical and therefore equivalent.
- Casting a value type may not preserve identity, however though through coercion may still be equivalent

Comment: Somewhat confusing, as implies `==` on value types calls `.Equals` which it does not unless overridden.

Comment: @Charlieface the question was seemingly more focused on refences, so the answer was tailored to it. Additionally, I was more leaning towards identity vs equality rightly or wrongly, which I believe is more useful. Though on saying that, a couple of the early points should probably be clarified